# update or insert information for each user in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to insert every user name to the MySQL database if the user is not in the specific table. Otherwise just update the specific value if a user is already there (increase counter with +1).

My issue is that it only insert one user and if the user is there, just only increasing the value (with +1) to that one user (last inserted user) and won't insert or update to another users.

**Session:**
  `$userName = $_SESSION['name'];`

**Query for display friends**:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM
  users u
  JOIN connections con on u.userName = con.Friend
  WHERE u.userName = '$userName'
  AND con.connectionStatus = '1'
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM
  users u
  JOIN connections con on u.userName = con.FriendReferee
  WHERE u.userName = '$userName'
  AND con.connectionStatus = '1'";
```

**Fetching friends from connection table:**

```
$result = $conn->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $friends = $row["Friend"];
   $friendRef = $row["FriendReferee"];
  if ($userName == $friends) {
  $userName = $friendRef;
  } elseif ($userName == $friendRef) {
    $userName = $friends;
  }
 }
}
```

**Insert or update user with value to a different table:**

```
 $result = $conn->query("SELECT id, userTo, counter FROM notbell WHERE userTo = '$userName'");
if($result->num_rows == 0 ) {
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO notbell (id, userTo, counter)
  VALUES ('', '$userName', '1')";
} else {
 mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE notbell
                     SET counter = counter + 1
                     WHERE userTo = '$userName'");
}
```

**Execute query:**

```
if ( $conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
  $prevUrl = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  header('Location: '.$prevUrl);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

I assume that I have to do with `foreach`, but not sure how should I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make colum name `userTo` unique from database and then please `onDuplicate` function of `mysqli`

```
INSERT INTO notbell (id, userTo, counter) VALUES (', '$userName', '1')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1;
```

Comment: How can I insert multiple users to the table if those users are not exists in the `notBell` table?

Comment: This query first check userTo in  a table and if not exist then insert and if found then it will increment 1 with courrent value.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `mysqli_query()` to execute `INSERT` query in `if` block:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO notbell (id, userTo, counter)
  VALUES ('', '$userName', '1')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the query:
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO notbell (id, userTo, counter) VALUES ('', '$userName', '1')";
**$result = $conn->query($sql2);**

Comment: That's not the problem here.

Comment: It's only execute one user to the MySQL